# How to filter array 3 levels deep without knowing the index? Getting wrong results

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array where I want to return all the replies where reply.body contains 'super'. Unfortunately I have only been able to return all posts that have a reply with this condition but it returns all replies instead of only the ones that meet the criteria. I'm not sure how I need to iterate over the posts, comments and replies to get the replies that meet the criteria.

**My array**

```
let posts = [
    { id: 1, body: 'First post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, body: 'First comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, comment_id: 1, body: 'First reply' }] }] },
    { id: 2, body: 'Second post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, body: 'Second post comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, comment_id: 1, body: 'Second reply' }] }] },
    { id: 3, body: 'Third post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, body: 'Test', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Test super reply' }, { id: 2, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Crazy comment' }] }] },
]
```

**Return all replies where body includes 'super'. But it return all posts.**

```
let replies = posts.filter(post => {
    return post.comments.some(comment => {
        return comment.replies.some(reply => {
            return reply.body.includes('super')
        })
    })
})
```

**This gives me the wrong result**

```
{ id: 3, body: 'Third post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, body: 'Test', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Test super reply' }, { id: 2, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Crazy comment' }] }] }
```

**Expected result:**

```
replies: [
    {
        id: 1,
        post_id: 3,
        body: 'Test super reply'
    },

    {
        id: 5,
        post_id: 9,
        body: 'Another super reply'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to first map the array to get all replies, then filter those replies.

```js
var posts = [
{ id: 1, body: 'First post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, body: 'First comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, comment_id: 1, body: 'First reply' }] }] },
{ id: 2, body: 'Second post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, body: 'Second post comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, comment_id: 1, body: 'Second reply' },{ id: 2, post_id: 1, comment_id: 1, body: 'Another super reply' }] }] },
{ id: 3, body: 'Third post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, body: 'Test', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Test super reply' }, { id: 2, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Crazy comment' }] }] }]

var replies = posts.flatMap(p=>p.comments.flatMap(c=>c.replies)).filter(reply=>reply.body.includes("super"))

console.log(replies);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!!

```js
let posts = [
    { id: 1, body: 'First post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, body: 'First comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, comment_id: 1, body: 'First reply' }] }] },
    { id: 2, body: 'Second post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, body: 'Second post comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, comment_id: 1, body: 'Second reply' }] }] },
    { id: 3, body: 'Third post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, body: 'Test', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Test super reply' }, { id: 2, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Crazy comment' }] }] },
]

let replies = [];
posts.filter(post => {
       post.comments.some(comment => {
          comment.replies.some(reply => {
            if(reply.body.includes('super')){
              replies.push(reply)
            }
        })
    })
})

console.log(replies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are filtering posts, you are getting back posts. Of you need replies, filter on replies and only iterate on posts.

Meaning you should do `posts.map`  instead of `posts.filter`

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps.sorry for variable names if anything appears to be non meaningful.

```
let posts = [
        { id: 1, body: 'First post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, body: 'First comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 1, comment_id: 1, body: 'First reply' }] }] },
        { id: 2, body: 'Second post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, body: 'Second post comment', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 2, comment_id: 1, body: 'Second reply' }] }] },
        { id: 3, body: 'Third post', comments: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, body: 'Test', replies: [{ id: 1, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Test super reply' }, { id: 2, post_id: 3, comment_id: 1, body: 'Crazy comment' }] }] },
    ]

    let filteredReplies=[];
    posts.forEach(function(element) {
    element.comments.forEach(function(comment){
    let filteredReplyFromComment=comment.replies.filter(replies=>{
    return replies.body.indexOf("super")!=-1;
    })

    if(filteredReplyFromComment.length>0)
    {
    filteredReplies.push(filteredReplyFromComment)
    }
    })
    return filteredReplies;
    });
    console.log(filteredReplies)
```